# Weights in Panel Data - Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, weighted-average

I have a pandas DataFrame that is indexed by monthly dates and contains 1's and 0's.

For each date (row), I would like to sum the row and then divide each data point by that sum in order to determine weights over time (if the datapoint is zero it should remain zero).

My data looks like this:

```
                A       B       C       D      
01-2001         1       1       0       1
02-2001         1       0       0       1
03-2001         1       0       0       1
04-2001         1       1       1       1
05-2001         1       1       1       0
```

The output should be as such:

```
                A       B       C       D      
01-2001         0.33    0.33    0       0.33
02-2001         0.5     0       0       0.5
03-2001         0.5     0       0       0.5
04-2001         0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25
05-2001         0.33    0.33    0.33    0
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
                A         B         C         D
01-2001  0.333333  0.333333  0.000000  0.333333
02-2001  0.500000  0.000000  0.000000  0.500000
03-2001  0.500000  0.000000  0.000000  0.500000
04-2001  0.250000  0.250000  0.250000  0.250000
05-2001  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.000000
```

And if you need [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html):

```
print df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).round(2)
            A     B     C     D
01-2001  0.33  0.33  0.00  0.33
02-2001  0.50  0.00  0.00  0.50
03-2001  0.50  0.00  0.00  0.50
04-2001  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25
05-2001  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.00
```